# load a unicode file help.htm into a webview in main thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, unicode, webview

I am trying load a file "assets/help-English/help.htm" into a webview [named howTo]. It catches IOException and loads the error message into the webview. I find this in the logcat "The application may be doing too much work on its main thread".

Do i need to create a thread for this process or do i have a different problem resulting in this message? I already have the code for creating a thread so that is not a problem. Just do not want to do that if i have missed something.

I think i may have missed something because i am certain that i have succesfully read from assets in the past without creating a separate thread.

The help files are in unicode so they will display in various languages. I have used Google Translate for that. They are simple unicode text files less than 10K bytes created using a simple HTML editor and NotePad.

The log.i statements display the expected text. The one in the While loop does not get executed.

```
AssetManager am = activity.getAssets();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(1024);
String lineHelp;

Log.i(TAG, "Locale = " + Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage());
Log.i(TAG, "Locale = " + Locale.getDefault());
try {
    InputStream is = am.open("help-" +     Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage()
     + "/help.htm");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
while((lineHelp = br.readLine()) != null) {
    Log.i(TAG, "lineHelp = " + lineHelp + "\n");
    sb.append(lineHelp);
}
} catch (IOException e) {
    sb.append(getString(R.string.HelpFileProblem));
    sb.append(e.getMessage());
}
lineHelp = sb.toString();
Log.i(TAG, "lineHelp = " + lineHelp);
howTo.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, lineHelp, "text/html", "unicode", null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't *need* to use a different thread, but if the assets file is large enough, reading the file will take enough time that Android will complain.

"If you have operations to perform that are not instantaneous, you should make sure to do them in separate threads ("background" or "worker" threads)." [Processes and Threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Threads).